# Necessity of infinitesimal steps for reversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics, mathematical-physics, ideal-gas, reversibility

Is there a mathematical proof for why a reversible process is one that has many infinitesimal equilibrium steps, rather than fewer large steps?

Maybe something along the lines of this?:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow0}[f(\Delta,r,....)]=0
\end{equation}

where $\Delta$ is the step size, $r$ the distance and $f$ the energy loss of the system.